# How to use generics to create generic NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a class that conforms to protocol `FetchedResultsControlable`:

```
protocol FetchedResultsControlable {
    var entityType: AnyClass
}
```

and now I need to create **NSFRC**:

```
class A: FetchedResultsControlable {
    var entityType: AnyClass {
        return Order.classForCoder()
    }
    func setupFetchedResultsController(delegate: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<entityType>(entityName: "\(entityType)")
        let identifierDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "identifier", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [identifierDescriptor]
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: storage.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

I need to create frc with generic types, but this doesn't work ;). How can I use generics to implement that functionality?

Comment: How does it “not work”? Does it not compile? Runtime errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: There is also an obvious typo: “entityType” vs “enetityType” – Is this your real (copy/pasted) code?

Comment: Yes, little misspelling is because of a writing;)

Comment: `AnyClass` as generic type of `NSFetchRequest` is nonsensical as `NSFetchRequest` is already constrained to `NSFetchRequestResult` which is far, far away from `AnyClass`